# Avoid multiple copying in vector in C++

Tags: c++, stl

My question is give below to avoid multiple copies in vector copying.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class DataValue {
public:

    DataValue() { std::cout << "DataValue constructor called" << std::endl; }
    DataValue(DataValue const& other) { cout << "DataValue copy constructor called" << std::endl; }
    ~DataValue() { std::cout << "DataValue destructor is called" << std::endl; }
private:

};

class ItemDataHistory {
public:
    ItemDataHistory() { std::cout << "ItemDataHistory constructor called" << std::endl; }
    // ItemDataHistory(ItemDataHistory const & other) { std::cout << "ItemDataHistory copy constructor called" << std::endl; }
    ~ItemDataHistory() { std::cout << "ItemDataHistory destructor called" << std::endl; }
    std::vector<DataValue>& GetVecDataValues() { return m_vecDataValues; }  

private:
    std::vector<DataValue> m_vecDataValues;
};

class DataReply {
public:

    DataReply() { std::cout << "Data reply constructor is called "<< std::endl; }
    ~DataReply() { std::cout << "Data reply destructor is called "<< std::endl; }
    DataReply(const DataReply& ) { std::cout << "Data reply copy constructor is called "<< std::endl; }

    std::vector<ItemDataHistory>& GetItemDataHistories() { return m_vecItemData; }  

private:
    // The list of DataValue
    std::vector<ItemDataHistory> m_vecItemData;
};



void main()
{

    DataValue dv1, dv2, dv3;
    ItemDataHistory itmDH;
    itmDH.GetVecDataValues().reserve(3);
    itmDH.GetVecDataValues().push_back(dv1);
    itmDH.GetVecDataValues().push_back(dv2);
    itmDH.GetVecDataValues().push_back(dv3);

    DataReply dr;
    dr.GetItemDataHistories().reserve(1);
    dr.GetItemDataHistories().push_back(itmDH); // Here copy consturtor of itemdatahistory is called and all data values are copied.
                                                    // Here I want to avoid data values constructor to be called again how can I avoid this
                                                    // How can I directly insert values of dv1, dv2, dv3 into "dr" with out using "itmDH"?
    return;
}
```

Note here I cannot use pointer in above std::vector m_vecItemData; in data reply class as these are interface classes from libary and don't have control on it and I am calling function so function may use data while data in scope

My question is given in above comment in code. Reason is that I have thousands of data values. To avoid multiple constructors of data values to be called, I want to insert data values directly to data reply (i.e., with out using itmDH local variable)

and other questions is

How I can reserve space of data values inside data reply?

Answer (score 0):

With C++11, you have two options:

- make your type `ItemDataHistory` movable and move your data (if possible) with `dr.GetItemDataHistories().push_back(std::move(itmDH));`
- look into new member function of containers, e.g. [`emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

Comment: what do you mean by ItemDataHistory  make movable? and other question is if itmDH goes out of scope will dr still contains valid data values. Thanks!

Comment: Google "move semantics C++", it's a bit to much for the Q/A format of SO. And yes, `dr` will contain valid values as long as you copied or moved `itmDH` into it.

Answer (score 0):

In **C++11,** you can use move semantics.

Instead of doing this:

```
itmDH.GetVecDataValues().push_back(dv1);
itmDH.GetVecDataValues().push_back(dv2);
itmDH.GetVecDataValues().push_back(dv3);
```

You could do this:

```
itmDH.GetVecDataValues().push_back(std::move(dv1));
itmDH.GetVecDataValues().push_back(std::move(dv2));
itmDH.GetVecDataValues().push_back(std::move(dv3));
```

Instead of copying values, they are simply moved into the vector.

And instead of copying *itmDH*

```
dr.GetItemDataHistories().push_back(itmDH);
```

you could move it as well:

```
dr.GetItemDataHistories().push_back(std::move(itmDH));
```

In addition you also need move constructors. Here's an example:

```
DataValue(DataValue&& other){
    std::cout << "DataValue move constructor called" << std::endl;
}
```

You may also declare and define move assignment operator:

```
DataValue& operator=(DataValue&& other){
    std::cout << "DataValue move assigment operator is called" << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

In order to fully understand move semantics (and rvalue references as well) please take a look at the following links:

http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html
http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html